# What does the symbol '<' mean on the mysql command line and where is the imported file saved?

Tags: mysql, command-line, custom-function

I gather from the context of the following page https://github.com/AtomBoy/double-metaphone that the following command has something to do with adding a custom function to the mysql server.  Here is the command that I don't understand:

> ***mysql yourDataBaseName -u root -p < metaphone.sql***

I successfully ran the command, and installed the function, however I'm still unclear on the complete function of the less than sign.  I understand that I am importing a .sql file.  In this case the sql file is a function.

Where is this function saved?

Comment: `<` is a *standard input redirection* symbol. In your case, program `mysql` will *see* file  `metaphone.sql` as standard input.

Comment: the data is stored in the data folder, that is configured in the my.ini/cnf every database has its own folder